# Whole Application get scrolled on mobile screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have used ReactTerminal and it's working fine on desktop screens but on mobile every touch on the terminal results in the whole application getting scrolled back to the top. The mobile user is not able to see terminal screen when they touch it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { ReactTerminal } from 'react-terminal';
const Terminal = () => {

// Rest of Code

  return (
    <div style={{ border: '2px solid var(--text-color)', backgroundColor: 'var(--background-color)', height: '100%' }}>
      <ReactTerminal
        prompt={<span style={promptStyling}>$ nishantb &gt;&gt;</span>}
        commands={commands}
        welcomeMessage={<span style={{ color: 'var(--text-color)  ' }}>{welcomeMessage}</span>}
        errorMessage={<span style={error}>Command not found!</span>}
        inputColor="var(--text-color)"
        outputColor="var(--text-color)"
        backgroundColor="var(--background-color)"
        theme={theme}

      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Terminal;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing might be related to scrolling behavior or event bubbling on touch devices.

Can you try wrapping your component with a `div` tag and stop event bubbling

```
const Terminal = () => {
  // Rest of Code

  const handleTouchStart = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  return (
    <div 
      onTouchStart={handleTouchStart} 
      style={{ border: '2px solid var(--text-color)', backgroundColor: 'var(--background-color)', height: '100%' }}
    >
      <ReactTerminal
        // Rest of props
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Tried, but still not working

Comment: I am not sure, can you reproduce it and share it in some sandbox